# Ringing across IGBT with Infineon driver IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, driver, igbt, ringing

I am testing the 1ED3123MC12H driver IC with an IKW15N120BH6 IGBT    in a buck converter circuit.

Vdc=30V, 0.6mH and Fsw=10 kHz.

[image]

Ringing is creating a problem.

How can I fix the ringing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ringing is often related to parasitics such as series inductance. Please show your layout and highlight the critical nets.

Comment: Looks pretty normal to me if I both (1) guessed your IGBT circuit and (2) guessed where you were probing. Too many guesses and not enough information in the question. Please fix. Here's another guess - your buck output voltage is meant to be about 10 or 11 volts DC?

Comment: A natural consequence of DCM operation.

Comment: Hello everyone.. Thank you for your responses. Yes I am IGBT and ptobing Vge. I kept 50% duty ratio and hence output voltage shpuld be 15V.

Comment: I quess E.T. phone home and the others do not answer to his request.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions... I got that my designing is very bad and hence I am going for PCB design of whole circuit by keeping driver circuit as near as possible to IGBT and check the Vge again

Answer (score 0):

J4/2 shall be connected to the floating GND of the PSU - J2/2, which of course shall not be connected to the earth. The input AC supply shall be fed through an isolating transformer.

But without knowing the layout and the probing technique, no conclusions can be made.

Comment: But normally we would isolate both of them to avoid complexity....

Comment: @RajaSekhar Use some application note and copy/paste the PCB layout. The gate driver and resistors have to be very close to the IGBT, and not connected with long leads. Your PCB layout is horrible.

Comment: Yes its horrible.. I am very much new to hardware design. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @RajaSekhar Flip the IC, so that output and gate resistors are as close as possible, remove the copper plane around those traces. Place the IGBT close to the driver IC. There should be visible isolation split of LV and HV side.  Have a look how it should like:  https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-UG-2021-03_EVAL-1ED3890MX12M-UserManual-v01_04-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4627aa5d4f5017aa9776e060d3c , you could use Recom RH-xx1509 for isolated PSU.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips.. Yes I will do that

Answer (score 0):

There is a loop somewhere with unwanted trace inductance in your circuit causing the ringing. Try these 2 possible solutions:
1- Connect capacitor  47nf- 100nf  across emmiter and collector of oscillating igbt or mosfet.
2- connect same value capacitors between power and ground as close as possible to power pins of ICs.